# Почему пользователь должен прикладывать скриншот рекламы, на которую он жалуется?

Tags: поддержка, реклама

Под рекламой в колонке справа увидел ссылку "Пожаловаться на рекламу". Нажал, выбрал причину, жму на "Отправить", а мне в ответ "приложите изображение рекламы, на которую жалуетесь". Это как? От пользователя ожидается, что он сделает скриншот? А сам сайт не в курсе, какую он рекламу показывается в данный момент на данной странице?

Адблок, например, скриншотов не просит...

Comment: Реклама выводится в отдельном iframe, поставщиком которого является Google. Ссылка "Пожаловаться на рекламу" - в корневом html-документе. Так что в общем случае в реальном времени сайт не в курсе, какую рекламу показывает.

Comment: @Nofate мне там показывается исключительно реклама SO с физиономией одного из сотрудников. Т.е. совсем не очевидно, что реклама приходит от третьей стороны.

Comment: Кстати, крестик в левом верхнем углу рекламы обрабатывается уже рекламной сетью гугла, которая знает, что показывает. В таком случае вам не нужно будет делать скриншот.

Comment: @Nofate я так вовремя успел [скриншот оформить](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371639/339911), оказывается.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На MSE есть вопрос с анонсом данной фичи "жалобы на рекламу" [Report this Ad Feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345476/339911) и там сказано следующее:

> We enforce strict guidelines on the types of advertisers we work with **but cannot fully control what is shown due to how advertising delivery works**.

Т.е. скриншот нужен в силу специфики работы доставки рекламы.